# Swift iBeacon use accuracy or rssi for distancing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibeacon, beacon

I have a room with 6 iBeacons and call an action if one of them is under 2.5 meters from the device, but that is not working very well because there a often big interferences, which caused the false Action.
My question is what is better for sorting these Beacons - using the rssi-value or the accuracy?

Below the Code I use for sorting/call the action:

```
if beacons.count > 0 {
        let sortedBeacons = beacons.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
            if first.accuracy == -1 || second.accuracy == -1 {
                return true
            }
            return first.accuracy < second.accuracy
        }
        let beacon = sortedBeacons[0]

        if beacon.major.intValue == helperMajorValue && beacon.accuracy < 2.5 {
            if beacon.accuracy != -1 {
                if triggeredMajor == 0 {
                    counter += 1
                } else if abs((helperMajorValue - triggeredMajor)) < 3 {
                    counter += 1
                }
            }
        } else {
            counter = 0
            helperMajorValue = beacon.major.intValue
        }
            if counter > 4 {
                counter = 0
                print("majorValue: \(beacon.major.intValue) distance: \(beacon.accuracy)")
                if beacon.accuracy < 2.5 {
                    startNavigation = true
                    majorValue = helperMajorValue
                    triggered = false
                }
            }

            if majorValue == 171 {
                //call action
            } else if majorValue == 170 {
                //call action
            } else if majorValue == 172 {
                //Call action
            }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference between using `CLBeacon`'s `rssi` or `accuracy` fields for sorting beacons is the variability or the number and the averaging interval.

**The accuracy field is averaged over approximately 20 seconds**, so it essentially gives you the estimated distance of where the device was over the past 20 seconds.  The real advantage is that this number is **much less noisy** than rssi, but **there is significant lag**.

**The rssi field is averaged over 1 second**, so it uses many fewer data points.  While it has **less time lag**, it also has a lot **more noise**.  For sorting purposes if using rssi, you will see the sort order jump around a lot more.

You must set your expectations appropriately for how accurate these numbers will be as estimates of distance as @Duncan-C describes in his answer.  But for some uses cases where precision is not important they can work very well.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
Can you recommend a good solution for this problem?
The Use Case is that the user go through this room with a device and gets automatically different Screens for the current area. How can I make sure that there gets no false Action triggered?
The Beacons are approximately 5 meters away fro each other.

Comment: Again, you must set your expectations appropriately.  That means realizing that you **CAN'T** make sure that there are no false actions triggered.  Beacon distance estimates are rough estimates.  One thing that will help make relative comparisons of distance better is to set a threshold.  For example, you might consider two beacons to be the same distance away unless one is estimated to be twice as close.

Answer (score 1):

The sad answer is "none of the above". The "accuracy" reading is the best source of distance from the beacon, but it is **very** crude. Think in terms of far, medium, close, and right on top of the phone. Trying to evaluate distance any more finely than that is pointless, and even that is iffy. The radio signal strength  is subject to so many variables that have nothing to do with distance that it isn't a very accurate measurement.